# Keeping the last visible item of a ListView when the size of the ListView changes

Tags: android, listview, layout

What I want is simple, well at least I thought it would be simple.
I just want a window where an EditText is on the bottom of the screen, and the rest of the space is filled with ListView.
Unfortunately, it did not work as I expected. What I want is the following image. Is there any easy way to do this in the XML, or should I write some special code for this?
[image: What I want]

My Problematic Android Source Code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/demolist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
     >
</ListView>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0">
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I'm looking for exactly the same behaviour.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**What you Want**

*Last Visible Item Without Keyboard*

[image: Last Visible Item Without Keyboard]

*Last Visible Item With Keyboard*

[image: Last Visible Item With Keyboard]

*Last Visible Item With larger input*

[image: Last Visible Item With larger input]

**Here is how i did it.**

Summary

- Set **android:stackFromBottom="true"** and **android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"** in your list view
- Set **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** in Activity
- Call **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();** when you add new chats so that the list view will always scroll to the last position
- Set **android:inputType="textMultiLine"** & **android:maxLines="4"** in EditText for growing text box

Details

***Activity***

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"></activity>
```

***Chat View***

> ```
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:id="@+id/chat_header"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="40dp"
>     android:padding="3dp" >
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/btnBackChat"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="35dp"
>         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>         android:background="@drawable/back_button" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/txt_name"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnBackChat"
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>         android:textSize="18sp" />
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/imgViewProfileChat"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="35dp"
>         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>         />
> </RelativeLayout>
>
> <ListView
>     android:id="@+id/listView1"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_above="@+id/form"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/chat_header"
>     android:stackFromBottom="true"
>     android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"/>
>
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:id="@+id/form"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>     <ImageButton
>         android:id="@+id/btnAttach"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>         android:contentDescription="@string/attach"
>         android:src="@drawable/attach_icon" />
>
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/txtChat"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSend"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnAttach"
>         android:inputType="textMultiLine"
>         android:maxLines="4" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/btnSend"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>         android:text="@string/send" />
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Comment: As I already mentioned in another comment, I'd prefer to avoid using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan". Also, doesn't your solution always scroll to the bottom of the list? I want whatever  item is at the bottom of the list view window to stay at the bottom of the window when the window shrinks, *NOT* for the list to stay scrolled to the end of the list. (Note, my application is not a chat application like the OP's -- I want the new item to be inserted where the user is looking at in the list, not at the bottom.)

Comment: You can use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" also with this solution. Then the actionbar won't disappear.

Answer (score 7):

I think you may want to use [AdapterView.getLastVisiblePosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getLastVisiblePosition%28%29) before displaying the keyboard.

Two solutions here:

- on EditText click
- thanks to an OnScrollListener (and its onScroll function) listening to your ListView

then use the [AdapterView.setSelection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setSelection%28int%29) to jump to this item (or index - 2 or index - 3) after EditText focus.

Comment: Awarded the bounty for being the only person to understand the question. I had already tried using the OnScrollListener, and using OnLayoutChangeListener to detect the appearance of the keyboard. I have had another go, and I'm still unhappy with the results. SetSelection() and smoothScrollToPosition(), etc. seem unreliable :-( I think I may have to give up on this UI altogether.

Comment: Also do not forget to request focus as well. lstMessages.requestFocus(); then clear it and request other elements focus if needed

Comment: You give me [the right clue to achieve this and keep `adjustResize`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34232863/2668136), thank you. I juste made few changes by using `setSelectionFromTop()` instead of `setSelection()` to display the last item just above the edittext.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your AndroidManifest.xml as below

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.SimpleListView"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
```

This should produce the output you want. Official [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) .

Optionally you can specify transcript mode(if you are working on some chat feature) for your list view if you want to scroll automatically to the end of listview. You can check the `android:transcriptMode="normal"` as well and see if that fits.

A related [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005239/268473). Official [android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:transcriptMode).

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/comments"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll">
```

This should solve most of your issues, maybe except for the last one(in the image) which I haven't tested.

Comment: I tried adjustPan already, but that scrolls the action bar out of view, and makes it awkward to scroll the list with the keyboard visible.

Transcript mode is no use either, unfortunately -- I don't want it to scroll to the bottom of the list. (I thought the OP spelled this out very well already, which is why I added a bounty to his post instead of starting my own.) I need the last *visible* item to remain the last visible item when the keyboard appears.

Comment: Hmm.. tricky, you could try to detect the softkeyboard height and manually adjust the height of the listview set the last visible position (if possible using setSelectionFromTop). Bit lot hackish solution though . Related SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534365/getting-the-dimensions-of-the-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 3):

Just override the method of ListView#onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)　like below:
PS:Your ListView's height can not be 0 anytime,if it may 0,not working.

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    final int lastVisiblePosition = getLastVisiblePosition();
    int firstVisiblePosition = getFirstVisiblePosition();

    View last = getChildAt(lastVisiblePosition - firstVisiblePosition);
    int top = last.getTop();
    final int newTop = top + (h - oldh);
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onSizeChanged(" + w + ", " + h + ", " + oldw + ", " + oldh + ")");
    if (mFocusSelector == null) {
        mFocusSelector = new FocusSelector();
    }
    post(mFocusSelector.setup(lastVisiblePosition, newTop));
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

private class FocusSelector implements Runnable {
    private int mPosition;
    private int mPositionTop;

    public FocusSelector setup(int position, int top) {
        mPosition = position;
        mPositionTop = top;
        return this;
    }

    public void run() {
        setSelectionFromTop(mPosition, mPositionTop);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually got the same behavior that you need by adding to `Activity` declaration in manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and to the `ListView` declaration `android:transcriptMode="normal"`. For both keyboard and orientation changes.

Answer (score 1):

I need this functionality too. Here's my attempt, but it doesn't quite work -- The scrolling is a bit erratic (doesn't always end up where it should) and it interferes with the preservation of the scroll position when rotating the screen.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getListView().addOnLayoutChangeListener(stickyLastItemHandler);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getListView().removeOnLayoutChangeListener(stickyLastItemHandler);
}

View.OnLayoutChangeListener stickyLastItemHandler = new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v,
            int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
            int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {

        final int heightChange = (bottom - top) - (oldBottom - oldTop);
        if (heightChange != 0) {
            ((AbsListView)v).smoothScrollBy(-heightChange, 1000);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: How do you want the last item to behave, snap so it's fully visible or just keep it as it currently is(like half, only a few pixels etc)?

Comment: Snap to fully visible would probably be tidiest, I think. My app is a task list, and using the edit box should add a new task immediately below the last visible one. (Following text entry I'd scroll the new item up into view.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through xml:

```
<ListView
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:layout_height=0dp
    android:layout_weight=1 />
```

Stacking from bottom will keep ListView scrolled down by default,
setting ListView's weight will fill all possible space within parent vertical LinearLayout.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't do what I need. The list will initially be scrolled to the bottom, but when the soft keyboard appears the behaviour is the same as it is without this flag.

Answer (score 1):

I created a layout engine for Android that allows you to listen for keyboard hidden and visible state changes (among many other core features). This library is available at http://phil-brown.github.io/AbLE/.

Simply add the `jar` to your `libs` directory (create this folder if it does not exist), and instead of inheriting from an `Activity`, inherit from `AbLEActivity`. Next, Override the methods `onKeyboardShown` and `onKeyboardHidden`, and in these you can animate your content view up or down as needed:

```
@Override
public void onKeyboardShown() {
    //animate up
}

@Override
public void onKeyboardHidden() {
    //animate down
}
```

Comment: What does this give me that OnLayoutChangeListener doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow these steps
--------------------
1. Update your activity in AndroidManifest.xml file like below
<activity
            android:name=".MyListActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

2. Set your list view with like below.
mListView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
mListView.setStackFromBottom(true);
```

I hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

In your ListAdapter, you could do something like this :

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

//buttonMore
if( position >= super.getCount()  )
      return textField ;

    ....
```

This way, you will always get your last item in the list as your textfield.

Comment: No. Please see my picture carefully. I specifically mentioned that it is not the last item but the last ‘visible‘ item. See the leftmost part of the picture.

Comment: You will get what you want. The solution I gave you makes the textfield the last item in the list. If not visible, as user didn't scroll down to the end of the list, then it's not visible...

Answer (score -1):

You need to set selection position... But - in a strange way, i don't really understand why - you need to do it with post()

```
public void ScrollToLast() {
    yourList.clearFocus();
    yourList.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            yourList.setSelection(items.size() - 1);
        }
    });
}
```

So you can add a TextWatcher for your editText and you can call this method there... So your list will scroll to bottom.