# AutoCompleteTextView's Suggest List overlapping with soft keyboard android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, autocompletetextview

I have a `AutocompleteTextView`. Suggests List will appear on typing  3 characters.Suggest list size to be be fixed i.e. 8 . Every thing is working fine except the suggest list getting overlapped with soft keyboard.
I am attaching the screen shots for the same
[image]

What should be done, suggestions please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [android:dropDownHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setDropDownHeight%28int%29)

Comment: is there any way by which i can set suggest list height till keyboard starts.?

Comment: You can programmatically calculate it by knowing screen size, soft keyboard height and textfield current position. Here's how you can find keyboard height http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534365/getting-the-dimensions-of-the-soft-keyboard

Comment: I am able to do this but on click of AutoCompleteTextView, suggest list is getting invisible.

Comment: @Vaibs then you should not use autocomplete but a simple list view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-make-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android