# Android Soft keyboard height, position on screen

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

When edit text got focus soft keyboard is launched that move's the layout above, so added this property in manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

Now i want to add edit text above of soft keyboard, but i'm not able to get soft key board height,position on screen. If i have these value i will be able to dynamically add edit text above of soft keyboard.

I had tried with different google searched codes but did not get any thing. Below are some links:

[Getting the dimensions of the soft keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534365/getting-the-dimensions-of-the-soft-keyboard)

[Is there any way in android to get the height of virtual keyboard of device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788959/is-there-any-way-in-android-to-get-the-height-of-virtual-keyboard-of-device)

Comment: I believe you can get the height and position in `adjustResize` mode, assuming that the keyboard is on the bottom of the screen. That mode also allows you to directly place Views as low as possible.

Comment: @Pietu1998: With this property my other layouts gets resized, so i dont want to resize them.