# How to get keyboard height when adjust nothing?

Tags: android, keyboard, height, popupwindow, adjustpan

I am trying to get android keyboard height with following code.

The popupWindow solution doesn't work in some devices , is there another solution?

```
parentLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    Rect r = new Rect();
                    parentLayout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                    int screenHeight = parentLayout.getRootView().getHeight();
                    int heightDifference = screenHeight - (r.bottom);

                    previousHeightDiffrence = heightDifference;

                       if (heightDifference > 100) {
                        isKeyBoardVisible = true;
                        changeKeyboardHeight(heightDifference);

                    } else {

                       if(emojiKeyboard.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE){
                          emojiKeyboard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                       isKeyBoardVisible = false;
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: Try link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534365/getting-the-dimensions-of-the-soft-keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with `insets` solution - where `rootWindowInsets.systemWindowInsetBottom` would include keyboard if present. Take a look at [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets#getSystemWindowInsetBottom())

Comment: Can you give me a liitle bit more info? I've added ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(rootView), but this callback called just once when Activity created and doesn't do anything when I open/close keyboard.

Comment: you can always call `View.requestApplyInsets()` to force new call

Comment: Yeah, but how do I know when should I call it if I don't get any callback when keyboard is opened/closed?

Answer (score -1):

```
final Window mRootWindow = getWindow();
        ll_main.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
            public void onGlobalLayout(){
                int screenHeight = ll_main.getRootView().getHeight();
                Rect r = new Rect();
                View view = mRootWindow.getDecorView();
                view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                int keyBoardHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;
            }
        });
```

Full code on this [link](http://android-designing.blogspot.in/2017/05/get-height-of-soft-keyboard-of-device.html). this link also help for AdjustNothing.