# Is there any way to detect the visibility of Keyboard in Android TV Leanback

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I am trying to detect whether the keyboard is visible or not. The standard way of detecting the keyboard in mobile does not work in Android TV.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The "new" standard way is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68380870/2910520, have you already tried this? (just asking)

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why you want to know the keyboard status?

If i had no other way i would:-

1. When you want the keyboard open ... force close and open and vice versa
2. Create a global boolean flag that would change depending on whether a textfield is clicked .. if clicked, boolean = true ... if keyboard opened(blooean = true), and back button pressed then set boolean = false ...

Comment: I wanted to hide the keyboard for an event

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for something like this

```
fun isKeyBoardVisible() = ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(requireView())?.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()) ?: false
```