# Keyboard covers screen instead of pushing up layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

I have a problem where when I click on my keyboard, the contents of my screen doesn't get pushed up--rather the keyboard simply overlaps everything (namely covers my `ListView`) on my screen. This is the structure of my layout:

```
<ScrollView>
  <RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
<ListView>
</ListView>
<LinearLayout>
  <EditText></EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

I nested my `RelativeLayout` in a `ScrollView` because I thought that would make my entire layout scrollable, which would "push up" all the layouts so that the user can view those parts while typing his or her response. I also have in my AndroidManifest.xml: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible|stateAlwaysHidden"` Here is an image of what is happening:

[image: Image of what is happening]

And here is my code. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/comments_coordinator_layout">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/comments_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/comments_coordinator_layout"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/view_post"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="175dp"
            android:background="#e6e6e6">

            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/poster_picture"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
                fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/poster_name"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:id="@+id/post_date"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
                android:layout_below="@id/poster_name"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/view_status" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
            android:id="@+id/lv_comments_feed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/send_message">
        </ListView>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/send_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/write_comment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="Comment back!"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send_comment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="send"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

EDIT: My attempt to add in a parent `LinearLayout` for `ScrollView`. Issue is now:
`The vertically scrolling ScrollView should not contain another vertically scrolling widget` when I hover over `ListView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/comments_coordinator_layout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/comments_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/comments_coordinator_layout"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/view_post"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
                android:background="#e6e6e6">

                <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/poster_picture"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
                    fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/poster_name"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:id="@+id/post_date"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
                    android:layout_below="@id/poster_name"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/view_status" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ListView
                    android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
                    android:id="@+id/lv_comments_feed"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/send_message">
                </ListView>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/send_message"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/write_comment"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="top|left"
                        android:hint="Comment back!"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/send_comment"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="send"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

EDIT: I think the best solution may be to create a custom `ListView`... that contains the same layout that is in each `ListView` item. Any suggestions or ideas on how to implement this?

EDIT: Tried @VanillaBoy's answer. I know the image produced is because I have `marginTop = 225 dp` but even if I remove it, when I click on my `EditText`, it only shows my `ListView` and my `RelativeLayout` above is hidden
[image]

EDIT: As per @Fllo's answer, I am still able to reproduce the error I had in the beginning with this layout, and so here is what I have in my layout. Also if it helps my Android Manifest looks like this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden">`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/comments_coordinator_layout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/comments_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/comments_coordinator_layout"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/view_post"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
                android:background="#e6e6e6">

                <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/poster_picture"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
                    fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/poster_name"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:id="@+id/post_date"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
                    android:layout_below="@id/poster_name"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/view_status" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/container_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/send_message">
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/send_message"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/write_comment"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="top|left"
                        android:hint="Comment back!"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/send_comment"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="send"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Try to put everything after app bar layout inside a scrollview

Comment: Yes it has something to do with your scrollView. Try nesting everything in there and it should do it. You might want to look at a question that asks the exact opposite of what you are asking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516216/how-to-avoid-soft-keyboard-pushing-up-my-layout

Comment: @AnswerDroid I can't put everything after the app bar layout inside a scroll view because I have a `ListView` there because I would have 2 vertical scrollviews. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @ShreyansSheth I tried to nest everything in there but I can't put my `ListView` embedded in a `ScrollView` would have 2 vertical scrollviews which isn't allowed. Would you have any other ideas?

Comment: Try pasting this in the XML file and running it. Of course, if it doesn't work, then Ctrl+Z :P http://ideone.com/C3YxKs . I understand you can't do something on these lines but if you don't nest it, those particular containers are not going to be scrollable.

Comment: @ShreyansSheth with your file, then it says:  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child` Any other suggestions? Or is there possibly like a way to make a custom list view?

Comment: @ShreyansSheth, you are missing a `LinearLayout` to contain `RelativeLayout`s children in your example ;)

Comment: Aaaah. @User1871869: http://ideone.com/VToE4t

Comment: @ShreyansSheth The two files are exactly the same that you posted. I have included Fllo's suggestion and I will post what I did in my question, but then I get an error saying: `The vertically scrolling ScrollView should not contain another vertically scrolling widget` when I hover over my `ListView` element in my XML file.

Comment: @Fllo, Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I tried to implement what you suggested and I have my attempt above, but I get an error saying: `The vertically scrolling ScrollView should not contain another vertically scrolling widget` when I hover over my ListView in my XML file. Would you have any suggestion to get around this?

Comment: Hey, in the `scrollview` add  `android:fillviewport="true"`

Comment: @VanillaBoy I just tried your suggestion but unfortunately all it does is removes the `RelativeLayout` out of view and I am left with a chunk of space followed by my `ListView`. Example is shown above. I know it is because I have `marginTop = 225 dp` but even if I remove it, when I click on my `EditText`, it only shows my `ListView` and my `RelativeLayout` above is hidden

Comment: You'll need to catch and prevent the scroll events on the inner `ListView` (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19311197/2668136) and [this one too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3495908/2668136)). However, an inner `ListView` is not the right thing to do, it takes too much work, and [should be avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3496042/2668136). Maybe you need to change your layout organization.

Comment: @Fllo thank you for the suggestion. I agree, I understand your point fully. How can I transform my `ListView` into lets say a bunch of `LinearLayouts` with the same format of those in the `ListView` item that I can programmatically add to my view, in place of having a `ListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an inner `ListView` with `ScrollView` should be avoided in Android. Indeed, these layouts have their own scroll detections and gestures. The solutions are to prevent the scroll gesture on the list or to calculate the height and expand it by default. But this will make too much work and don't respect the Android pattern and guidelines.

Instead of replace `ListView` by `LinearLayout` and keep the parent's `ScrollView`, as my old answer pointed out, I found a possible workaround, which has these steps:

- Create your own `ListView`
- Override `onSizeChanged()` which redraws the `ListView` when keyboard is opening
- Get the `lastVisiblePosition` and retrieve its height in the previous method
- Finally, move the list to the previous `lastVisiblePosition` and calculate the offset
- Beside, set a `headerView` for the header picture container
- And you need to update the child item's height before the user opens the
  keyboard, so you could update the value in `onClickListener` of the
  `EditText`

And it needs this kind of layouts:

- layout's activity:

  ```
  <CoordinatorLayout>
      <AppBarLayout>
          ...
      </AppBarLayout>
      <RelativeLayout>
          <CustomListView />
          <LinearLayout>
              ...
          </LinearLayout>
      </RelativeLayout>
  </CoordinatorLayout>
  ```
- header's layout (which will be above the list):

  ```
  <RelativeLayout>
      <SimpleDraweeView />
      <TextView />
      ...
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

Hum, that's all... So, good to go:

#### Create a `Listview`:

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView {
    // last height item variable (updated from Activity)
    public int lastItemHeight = 0;

    public CustomListView(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

#### Override `onSizeChanged()`:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, final int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    // save last position visible before resize
    final int lastPosition = super.getLastVisiblePosition();
    // call super SizeChanged method
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    // after resizing, show the last visible item at the bottom of new listview's height, above the edit text
    // see : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSelectionFromTop(int, int)
    super.setSelectionFromTop(lastPosition, (h - lastItemHeight));
}
```

That's all for the `ListView`.
The `lastItemHeight` variable will be updated when the user clicks on the input (below the list, thanks to setting your "header" picture container as a `headerView` in your `Activity`).

Now, let see the `Activity`:

#### Setup your custom `ListView` and your `Adapter`:

```
// get custom listview element
final CustomListView list = (CustomListView) findViewById(R.id.container_list);
// example items child
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
for (int n=0; n<25; ++n) items.add("Blablabla n."+n);
// example adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item_list_text_simple, android.R.id.text1, items);
```

#### Create the `HeaderView` and set the `Adapter`:

```
// prepare the header content with picture
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.test_header_image, null);
// set datas to the header elements (example)
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/fresco/gh-pages/static/fresco-logo.png");
SimpleDraweeView draweeView = (SimpleDraweeView) header.findViewById(R.id.poster_picture);
draweeView.setImageURI(uri);
// add the header to listview
list.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
// set the adapter
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

#### Handle the softkeyboard open with `EditText.setOnClickListener`:

```
// when the user clicks on EditText...
editMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // set a new Thread
        list.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // get last position of child
                int lastPosition = list.getLastVisiblePosition() - 1;
                // if the list can give the view's last child
                if (list.getChildAt(lastPosition) != null) {
                    // update the height of the last child in custom listview
                    list.lastItemHeight = list.getChildAt(lastPosition).getHeight();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

That's all for the code! And the last thing (Ow.. where is the end?), here's the layouts:

#### The main layout of `Activity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/comments_coordinator_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar ... />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <com.package.name.CustomListView
            android:id="@+id/container_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/send_message"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/send_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText ... />

            <Button ... />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

#### The head layout of `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/view_post"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#e6e6e6">

    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView ... />

    <TextView ... />

    <TextView ... />

    <TextView ... />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Aw! I've finally finished. I really hope you will be able to have the right behaviour. I tested it, and it seems to work good enough.
[Here's another workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16230955/2668136) with `adjustPan`, but you have to keep your list starting at the bottom. Whereas this solution keeps any child at the bottom of the list when it's resize.

Hope you'll enjoy it ;)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this. Your logic totally makes sense. Unfortunately I still get the same issue that I was getting in the very beginning. I set my `ScrollView fillViewPorts=true` so that my `container_list` could be expanded. I followed all your instructions step by step on the Java side, but I think there might be something wrong with my XML file? But I don't see what would be wrong... I have posted what I have above.

Comment: Weird thing is my view won't even scroll.. I have no idea why!

Comment: I even tried to change my ScrollView into a `NestedScrollView` but I can't seem to inflate it as it says `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class NestedScrollView`

Comment: Yes, this layout can be ugly to achieve what you want and, I had the same problem with `LinearLayout` and the missing scroll event. I finally found a workaround to do it, but it's more work than replace `ListView` by `LinearLayout`. Instead, I found how to keep your list but without `ScrollView`. Can you confirm, @user1871869, that your final wish is to keep the child item above the `EditText` when the window is resizing? I'll edit my answer with all the steps I found.

Comment: Yes that is my wish. I'm having so much trouble with this but definitely what you say is what i want. Thanks for helping me through all this I really appreciate it.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

add this in your manifest under Activity

```
<activity .......
....................
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

Comment: I already have that put into my activity. Any other suggestions?

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: I have tried that but if I have `adjustPan` then I only my `ListView` shows and my `RelativeLayout` is hidden.

Comment: @GauravPolekar `adjustPan` is not the same as `adjustResize` : "This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window."